# Смена иконки svg при прокрутки ползунка громкости

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть у знатоков такое решение!

Как реализовать смену иконки svg слаидара громкости.
Например:

Громкость на 100% иконка такая -

```html
<svg width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M12.1402 4.90978C11.426 5.25674 10.5209 5.85164 9.2311 6.70205L9.01216 6.84641C8.9955 6.8574 8.97905 6.86824 8.96283 6.87895C8.58263 7.12974 8.31931 7.30343 8.03077 7.43078C7.74641 7.55627 7.44756 7.64593 7.14108 7.69768C6.83009 7.7502 6.51464 7.75013 6.05918 7.75004C6.03974 7.75004 6.02004 7.75003 6.00008 7.75003C4.55641 7.75003 4.06911 7.76631 3.6548 7.958C3.25445 8.14323 2.82804 8.54443 2.6188 8.93278C2.40052 9.33789 2.36045 9.75309 2.2834 11.0173C2.26225 11.3642 2.25 11.6968 2.25 12C2.25 12.3033 2.26225 12.6358 2.2834 12.9828C2.36045 14.247 2.40052 14.6622 2.6188 15.0673C2.82804 15.4556 3.25445 15.8568 3.6548 16.0421C4.06911 16.2338 4.55641 16.25 6.00008 16.25C6.02004 16.25 6.03973 16.25 6.05917 16.25C6.51464 16.2499 6.83009 16.2499 7.14108 16.3024C7.44756 16.3541 7.74641 16.4438 8.03077 16.5693C8.31931 16.6966 8.58263 16.8703 8.96282 17.1211C8.97905 17.1318 8.99549 17.1427 9.01216 17.1537L9.2311 17.298C10.5209 18.1484 11.426 18.7433 12.1402 19.0903C12.8525 19.4363 13.2087 19.4502 13.4578 19.3651C13.5952 19.3183 13.7297 19.2498 13.8485 19.1664C14.0651 19.0141 14.2626 18.7195 14.4015 17.9482C14.541 17.1733 14.5924 16.1014 14.6635 14.5706C14.7156 13.451 14.75 12.5118 14.75 12C14.75 11.4883 14.7156 10.549 14.6635 9.42946C14.5924 7.89871 14.541 6.82677 14.4015 6.05188C14.2626 5.28052 14.0651 4.98595 13.8485 4.8337C13.7297 4.75023 13.5952 4.68181 13.4578 4.63492C13.2087 4.54989 12.8525 4.56376 12.1402 4.90978ZM11.4848 3.56055C12.3108 3.15928 13.1241 2.9361 13.9423 3.21531C14.2142 3.30809 14.4759 3.44128 14.7109 3.60646C15.417 4.10266 15.7159 4.88667 15.8778 5.78612C16.037 6.67048 16.0914 7.84243 16.1592 9.30232L16.1619 9.35983C16.2137 10.4748 16.25 11.448 16.25 12C16.25 12.552 16.2137 13.5253 16.1619 14.6402L16.1592 14.6977C16.0914 16.1576 16.037 17.3296 15.8778 18.2139C15.7159 19.1134 15.417 19.8974 14.7109 20.3936C14.4759 20.5588 14.2142 20.692 13.9423 20.7848C13.1241 21.064 12.3108 20.8408 11.4848 20.4395C10.6712 20.0443 9.68413 19.3934 8.45327 18.5819L8.18647 18.4059C7.73856 18.1106 7.58448 18.0119 7.42513 17.9416C7.25452 17.8663 7.0752 17.8125 6.89132 17.7814C6.71956 17.7524 6.5366 17.75 6.00008 17.75C5.94569 17.75 5.89203 17.7501 5.83907 17.7501C4.62215 17.7507 3.77659 17.7512 3.02496 17.4034C2.33016 17.082 1.66141 16.4527 1.29828 15.7788C0.905663 15.0501 0.859593 14.2881 0.794087 13.2045C0.791489 13.1615 0.788861 13.1181 0.786179 13.0741C0.763733 12.7058 0.75 12.3416 0.75 12C0.75 11.6585 0.763733 11.2943 0.786179 10.926C0.788861 10.882 0.791489 10.8385 0.794087 10.7955C0.859593 9.712 0.905663 8.94996 1.29828 8.22128C1.66141 7.54732 2.33016 6.9181 3.02496 6.59664C3.77659 6.24889 4.62215 6.24933 5.83906 6.24998C5.89203 6.25 5.94569 6.25003 6.00008 6.25003C6.5366 6.25003 6.71956 6.24762 6.89132 6.21862C7.0752 6.18757 7.25452 6.13377 7.42513 6.05848C7.58448 5.98815 7.73856 5.88945 8.18647 5.59411L8.45328 5.4182C9.68414 4.60662 10.6712 3.95576 11.4848 3.56055ZM19.5199 5.42408C19.8381 5.1589 20.311 5.2019 20.5762 5.52011L20 6.00024C20.5762 5.52011 20.5762 5.52011 20.5762 5.52011L20.5773 5.52148L20.5786 5.52303L20.5816 5.52664L20.5891 5.53591C20.5948 5.543 20.6018 5.55194 20.6102 5.56272C20.6269 5.5843 20.6486 5.6133 20.6748 5.64986C20.727 5.723 20.7966 5.8264 20.8775 5.96125C21.0394 6.23106 21.2462 6.62623 21.45 7.15601C21.8582 8.21738 22.25 9.80868 22.25 12.0002C22.25 14.1918 21.8582 15.7831 21.45 16.8445C21.2462 17.3743 21.0394 17.7694 20.8775 18.0392C20.7966 18.1741 20.727 18.2775 20.6748 18.3506C20.6486 18.3872 20.6269 18.4162 20.6102 18.4378C20.6052 18.4442 20.6007 18.45 20.5966 18.4551C20.5939 18.4586 20.5914 18.4617 20.5891 18.4646L20.5816 18.4739L20.5786 18.4775L20.5773 18.479C20.5773 18.479 20.5762 18.4804 20 18.0002L20.5762 18.4804C20.311 18.7986 19.8381 18.8416 19.5199 18.5764C19.2032 18.3125 19.1591 17.8429 19.42 17.5247M19.42 17.5247C19.42 17.5247 19.4218 17.5224 19.4235 17.5202C19.4288 17.5134 19.4393 17.4996 19.4542 17.4788C19.4839 17.4371 19.5315 17.367 19.5913 17.2675C19.7106 17.0686 19.8788 16.7512 20.05 16.306C20.3918 15.4174 20.75 14.0087 20.75 12.0002C20.75 9.99181 20.3918 8.58311 20.05 7.69448C19.8788 7.24926 19.7106 6.93192 19.5913 6.73299C19.5315 6.63347 19.4839 6.56343 19.4542 6.52172C19.4393 6.50086 19.4288 6.48709 19.4235 6.48024C19.4218 6.47803 19.42 6.47578 19.42 6.47578L19.4235 6.48024L19.422 6.47812L19.42 6.47578C19.1591 6.15763 19.2032 5.68797 19.5199 5.42408M17.6358 8.34463C17.9979 8.14347 18.4545 8.27392 18.6556 8.63601L18.0276 8.9849C18.6556 8.63602 18.6556 8.63601 18.6556 8.63601L18.6563 8.63732L18.6571 8.63872L18.6588 8.64176L18.6626 8.64888L18.6723 8.66723C18.6795 8.6813 18.6884 8.69906 18.6986 8.72057C18.7191 8.76359 18.7451 8.82159 18.7745 8.89514C18.8333 9.0423 18.9059 9.25124 18.9765 9.52646C19.1178 10.0774 19.25 10.8901 19.25 12.0002C19.25 13.1104 19.1178 13.9231 18.9765 14.474C18.9059 14.7492 18.8333 14.9582 18.7745 15.1053C18.7451 15.1789 18.7191 15.2369 18.6986 15.2799C18.6884 15.3014 18.6795 15.3192 18.6723 15.3333L18.6626 15.3516L18.6588 15.3587L18.6571 15.3618L18.6563 15.3632C18.6563 15.3632 18.6556 15.3645 18.0276 15.0156L18.6556 15.3645C18.4545 15.7266 17.9979 15.857 17.6358 15.6559C17.2768 15.4564 17.1455 15.0058 17.3393 14.6453L17.3443 14.635C17.3512 14.6206 17.3643 14.5919 17.3818 14.5483C17.4167 14.4611 17.4691 14.3137 17.5235 14.1015C17.6322 13.6774 17.75 12.9901 17.75 12.0002C17.75 11.0104 17.6322 10.3231 17.5235 9.89902C17.4691 9.68675 17.4167 9.53944 17.3818 9.45222C17.3643 9.40858 17.3512 9.37986 17.3443 9.36547L17.3393 9.35523C17.1455 8.99465 17.2768 8.54408 17.6358 8.34463Z" fill="#1C274C"/>
</svg>
```

А если звук 50% иконка такая -

```html
<svg width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M12.1402 4.90978C11.426 5.25674 10.5209 5.85164 9.2311 6.70205L9.01216 6.84641C8.9955 6.8574 8.97905 6.86824 8.96283 6.87895C8.58263 7.12974 8.31931 7.30343 8.03077 7.43078C7.74641 7.55627 7.44756 7.64593 7.14108 7.69768C6.83009 7.7502 6.51464 7.75013 6.05918 7.75004C6.03974 7.75004 6.02004 7.75003 6.00008 7.75003C4.55641 7.75003 4.06911 7.76631 3.6548 7.958C3.25445 8.14323 2.82804 8.54443 2.6188 8.93278C2.40052 9.33789 2.36045 9.75309 2.2834 11.0173C2.26225 11.3642 2.25 11.6968 2.25 12C2.25 12.3033 2.26225 12.6358 2.2834 12.9828C2.36045 14.247 2.40052 14.6622 2.6188 15.0673C2.82804 15.4556 3.25445 15.8568 3.6548 16.0421C4.06911 16.2338 4.55641 16.25 6.00008 16.25C6.02004 16.25 6.03973 16.25 6.05917 16.25C6.51464 16.2499 6.83009 16.2499 7.14108 16.3024C7.44756 16.3541 7.74641 16.4438 8.03077 16.5693C8.31931 16.6966 8.58263 16.8703 8.96282 17.1211C8.97905 17.1318 8.99549 17.1427 9.01216 17.1537L9.2311 17.298C10.5209 18.1484 11.426 18.7433 12.1402 19.0903C12.8525 19.4363 13.2087 19.4502 13.4578 19.3651C13.5952 19.3183 13.7297 19.2498 13.8485 19.1664C14.0651 19.0141 14.2626 18.7195 14.4015 17.9482C14.541 17.1733 14.5924 16.1014 14.6635 14.5706C14.7156 13.451 14.75 12.5118 14.75 12C14.75 11.4883 14.7156 10.549 14.6635 9.42946C14.5924 7.89871 14.541 6.82677 14.4015 6.05188C14.2626 5.28052 14.0651 4.98595 13.8485 4.8337C13.7297 4.75023 13.5952 4.68181 13.4578 4.63492C13.2087 4.54989 12.8525 4.56376 12.1402 4.90978ZM11.4848 3.56055C12.3108 3.15928 13.1241 2.9361 13.9423 3.21531C14.2142 3.30809 14.4759 3.44128 14.7109 3.60646C15.417 4.10266 15.7159 4.88667 15.8778 5.78612C16.037 6.67048 16.0914 7.84243 16.1592 9.30232L16.1619 9.35983C16.2137 10.4748 16.25 11.448 16.25 12C16.25 12.552 16.2137 13.5253 16.1619 14.6402L16.1592 14.6977C16.0914 16.1576 16.037 17.3296 15.8778 18.2139C15.7159 19.1134 15.417 19.8974 14.7109 20.3936C14.4759 20.5588 14.2142 20.692 13.9423 20.7848C13.1241 21.064 12.3108 20.8408 11.4848 20.4395C10.6712 20.0443 9.68413 19.3934 8.45327 18.5819L8.18647 18.4059C7.73856 18.1106 7.58448 18.0119 7.42513 17.9416C7.25452 17.8663 7.0752 17.8125 6.89132 17.7814C6.71956 17.7524 6.5366 17.75 6.00008 17.75C5.94569 17.75 5.89203 17.7501 5.83907 17.7501C4.62215 17.7507 3.77659 17.7512 3.02496 17.4034C2.33016 17.082 1.66141 16.4527 1.29828 15.7788C0.905663 15.0501 0.859593 14.2881 0.794087 13.2045C0.791489 13.1615 0.788861 13.1181 0.786179 13.0741C0.763733 12.7058 0.75 12.3416 0.75 12C0.75 11.6585 0.763733 11.2943 0.786179 10.926C0.788861 10.882 0.791489 10.8385 0.794087 10.7955C0.859593 9.712 0.905663 8.94996 1.29828 8.22128C1.66141 7.54732 2.33016 6.9181 3.02496 6.59664C3.77659 6.24889 4.62215 6.24933 5.83906 6.24998C5.89203 6.25 5.94569 6.25003 6.00008 6.25003C6.5366 6.25003 6.71956 6.24762 6.89132 6.21862C7.0752 6.18757 7.25452 6.13377 7.42513 6.05848C7.58448 5.98815 7.73856 5.88945 8.18647 5.59411L8.45328 5.4182C9.68414 4.60662 10.6712 3.95576 11.4848 3.56055Z" fill="#1C274C"/>
<path d="M18.6563 8.63711C18.4552 8.27502 17.9979 8.14325 17.6358 8.34441C17.2768 8.54386 17.1455 8.99444 17.3393 9.35501C17.3462 9.36941 17.3643 9.40837 17.3818 9.45201C17.4167 9.53922 17.4691 9.68653 17.5235 9.89881C17.6322 10.3229 17.75 11.0101 17.75 12C17.75 12.9899 17.6322 13.6772 17.5235 14.1013C17.4691 14.3135 17.4167 14.4608 17.3818 14.5481L17.3393 14.645C17.1455 15.0056 17.2768 15.4562 17.6358 15.6557C17.9979 15.8568 18.4711 15.6951 18.6723 15.333C18.6795 15.319 18.6884 15.3012 18.6986 15.2797C18.7191 15.2367 18.7451 15.1787 18.7745 15.1051C18.8333 14.958 18.9059 14.749 18.9765 14.4738C19.1178 13.9229 19.25 13.1102 19.25 12C19.25 10.8899 19.1178 10.0772 18.9765 9.52625C18.9059 9.25103 18.8333 9.04209 18.7745 8.89493C18.7451 8.82138 18.7191 8.76338 18.6986 8.72036C18.6884 8.69885 18.6636 8.65118 18.6563 8.63711Z" fill="#1C274C"/>
</svg>
```

Если громкость звука ниже 20 то иконка такая -

```html
<svg width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.6402 4.90978C14.926 5.25674 14.0209 5.85164 12.7311 6.70205L12.5122 6.84641C12.4955 6.8574 12.4791 6.86824 12.4628 6.87895C12.0826 7.12974 11.8193 7.30343 11.5308 7.43078C11.2464 7.55627 10.9476 7.64593 10.6411 7.69768C10.3301 7.7502 10.0146 7.75013 9.55918 7.75004C9.53974 7.75004 9.52004 7.75003 9.50008 7.75003C8.05641 7.75003 7.56911 7.76631 7.1548 7.958C6.75445 8.14323 6.32804 8.54443 6.1188 8.93278C5.90052 9.33789 5.86045 9.75309 5.7834 11.0173C5.76225 11.3642 5.75 11.6968 5.75 12C5.75 12.3033 5.76225 12.6358 5.7834 12.9828C5.86045 14.247 5.90052 14.6622 6.1188 15.0673C6.32804 15.4556 6.75445 15.8568 7.1548 16.0421C7.56911 16.2338 8.05641 16.25 9.50008 16.25C9.52004 16.25 9.53973 16.25 9.55917 16.25C10.0146 16.2499 10.3301 16.2499 10.6411 16.3024C10.9476 16.3541 11.2464 16.4438 11.5308 16.5693C11.8193 16.6966 12.0826 16.8703 12.4628 17.1211C12.479 17.1318 12.4955 17.1427 12.5122 17.1537L12.7311 17.298C14.0209 18.1484 14.926 18.7433 15.6402 19.0903C16.3525 19.4363 16.7087 19.4502 16.9578 19.3651C17.0952 19.3183 17.2297 19.2498 17.3485 19.1664C17.5651 19.0141 17.7626 18.7195 17.9015 17.9482C18.041 17.1733 18.0924 16.1014 18.1635 14.5706C18.2156 13.451 18.25 12.5118 18.25 12C18.25 11.4883 18.2156 10.549 18.1635 9.42946C18.0924 7.89871 18.041 6.82677 17.9015 6.05188C17.7626 5.28052 17.5651 4.98595 17.3485 4.8337C17.2297 4.75023 17.0952 4.68181 16.9578 4.63492C16.7087 4.54989 16.3525 4.56376 15.6402 4.90978ZM14.9848 3.56055C15.8108 3.15928 16.6241 2.9361 17.4423 3.21531C17.7142 3.30809 17.9759 3.44128 18.2109 3.60646C18.917 4.10266 19.2159 4.88667 19.3778 5.78612C19.537 6.67048 19.5914 7.84243 19.6592 9.30232L19.6619 9.35983C19.7137 10.4748 19.75 11.448 19.75 12C19.75 12.552 19.7137 13.5253 19.6619 14.6402L19.6592 14.6977C19.5914 16.1576 19.537 17.3296 19.3778 18.2139C19.2159 19.1134 18.917 19.8974 18.2109 20.3936C17.9759 20.5588 17.7142 20.692 17.4423 20.7848C16.6241 21.064 15.8108 20.8408 14.9848 20.4395C14.1712 20.0443 13.1841 19.3934 11.9533 18.5819L11.6865 18.4059C11.2386 18.1106 11.0845 18.0119 10.9251 17.9416C10.7545 17.8663 10.5752 17.8125 10.3913 17.7814C10.2196 17.7524 10.0366 17.75 9.50008 17.75C9.44569 17.75 9.39203 17.7501 9.33907 17.7501C8.12215 17.7507 7.27659 17.7512 6.52496 17.4034C5.83016 17.082 5.16141 16.4527 4.79828 15.7788C4.40566 15.0501 4.35959 14.2881 4.29409 13.2045C4.29149 13.1615 4.28886 13.1181 4.28618 13.0741C4.26373 12.7058 4.25 12.3416 4.25 12C4.25 11.6585 4.26373 11.2943 4.28618 10.926C4.28886 10.882 4.29149 10.8385 4.29409 10.7955C4.35959 9.712 4.40566 8.94996 4.79828 8.22128C5.16141 7.54732 5.83016 6.9181 6.52496 6.59664C7.27659 6.24889 8.12215 6.24933 9.33906 6.24998C9.39203 6.25 9.44569 6.25003 9.50008 6.25003C10.0366 6.25003 10.2196 6.24762 10.3913 6.21862C10.5752 6.18757 10.7545 6.13377 10.9251 6.05848C11.0845 5.98815 11.2386 5.88945 11.6865 5.59411L11.9533 5.4182C13.1841 4.60662 14.1712 3.95576 14.9848 3.56055Z" fill="#1C274C"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как можно это реализовать, только вот вместо `<img>` ваша `svg` иконка.

```js
const volumeRange = document.getElementById('volumeRange');

const volumeHigh = document.getElementById('volumeHigh');
const volumeMedium = document.getElementById('volumeMedium');
const volumeLow = document.getElementById('volumeLow');

volumeRange.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const volumeValue = volumeRange.value;

  if (volumeValue >= 80) {
    // Тут можем делать все что захотим с иконками
    volumeHigh.style.opacity = 1;
    volumeMedium.style.opacity = 0.5;
    volumeLow.style.opacity = 0.5;
  } else if (volumeValue >= 20) {
    volumeHigh.style.opacity = 0.5;
    volumeMedium.style.opacity = 1;
    volumeLow.style.opacity = 0.5;
  } else {
    volumeHigh.style.opacity = 0.5;
    volumeMedium.style.opacity = 0.5;
    volumeLow.style.opacity = 1;
  }
});
```

```css
.volume-slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.volume-icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
}

img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#volumeHigh {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#volumeMedium {
  opacity: 1;
}

#volumeLow {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="volume-slider">
  <input type="range" id="volumeRange" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="1">
  <div class="volume-icons">
    <img src="https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/s8h1wbC0Q6mkDZx9Idb8rg.png" id="volumeLow" alt="Low Volume">
    <img src="https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/PK3F1b_KRxGY7IflgTEa2w.png" id="volumeMedium" alt="Medium Volume">
    <img src="https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/jaZlenjDRGCVQEv5Qio5aA.png" id="volumeHigh" alt="High Volume">
  </div>
</div>
```

Еще могу предложить вариант смены src при движении слайдера, тогда и код будет упрощен:

```js
const volumeRange = document.getElementById('volumeRange');
const volumeIcon = document.getElementById('volumeIcon');

volumeRange.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const volumeValue = volumeRange.value;

  if (volumeValue >= 80) {
    volumeIcon.src = 'https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/jaZlenjDRGCVQEv5Qio5aA.png';
  } else if (volumeValue >= 20) {
    volumeIcon.src = 'https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/PK3F1b_KRxGY7IflgTEa2w.png';
  } else {
    volumeIcon.src = 'https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/s8h1wbC0Q6mkDZx9Idb8rg.png';
  }
});
```

```css
.volume-slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="volume-slider">
  <input type="range" id="volumeRange" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="1">
  <img src="https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/PK3F1b_KRxGY7IflgTEa2w.png" id="volumeIcon" alt="Volume">
</div>
```

Ну и еще вариант по скрытию иконок и вывод только нужной:

```js
const volumeRange = document.getElementById('volumeRange');
const volumeHigh = document.getElementById('volumeHigh');
const volumeMedium = document.getElementById('volumeMedium');
const volumeLow = document.getElementById('volumeLow');

volumeRange.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const volumeValue = volumeRange.value;

  volumeHigh.style.display = 'none';
  volumeMedium.style.display = 'none';
  volumeLow.style.display = 'none';

  if (volumeValue >= 80) {
    volumeHigh.style.display = 'block';
  } else if (volumeValue >= 20) {
    volumeMedium.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    volumeLow.style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

```css
.volume-slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.volume-icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: none;
  /* Скрываем все иконки по умолчанию */
}

#volumeMedium {
  display: block;
  /* Показываем иконку Medium по умолчанию */
}
```

```html
<div class="volume-slider">
  <input type="range" id="volumeRange" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="1">
  <div class="volume-icons">
    <img src="https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/s8h1wbC0Q6mkDZx9Idb8rg.png" id="volumeLow" alt="Low Volume">
    <img src="https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/PK3F1b_KRxGY7IflgTEa2w.png" id="volumeMedium" alt="Medium Volume">
    <img src="https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/jaZlenjDRGCVQEv5Qio5aA.png" id="volumeHigh" alt="High Volume">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Привет! Спасибо большое!

Comment: Пожалуйста! Если ответ является тем что вам нужно, вы можете оставить галочку "ответ" :)

Comment: Смотри у тебя 3 иконки вряд, и они отключаются при движение слайдера. А можно упростить как-то код, чтобы иконка была одна и менялась иконка на одном и том же месте не мешая другим и не светилась за другими иконками (*"не светилась за другими иконками" Я подразумеваю чтобы они не были наложены друг на друга, как 2 лежачие фотографий на столе.)?

Comment: Обновил ответ, думаю сейчас нормально

Comment: Спасибо большое!